# Concatenating two values of different dictionaries and deleting the latter in Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, python-2.7

This is the data structure i have

```
{"A": [
         { 'key1 a' : 'value1',
           'key2 a' : 'A'
           'key3 a' : 'xyz'
         },

         { 'key1 a' : '',
           'key2 a' : 'B'
           'key3 a' : '' 
         },

         { 'key1 a' : 'value3',  
           'key2 a' : 'value4'
           'key3 a' : 'xyz' 
         }
      ],
 "B": [
         { 'key1 b' : 'value1',
           'key2 b' : 'A'
           'key3 b' : 'xyz'
         },

         { 'key1 b' : '',
           'key2 b' : 'C'
           'key3 b' : '' 
         },

         { 'key1 b' : 'value3',  
           'key2 b' : 'value4'
           'key3 b' : 'xyz' 
         }
      ]
}
```

Now,
I would like to concatenate the value of a dictionary whose all other fields are empty other than key2 if this holds true then the value of key2 should be concatenated with the previous dictionaries key2 and should delete itself.
Expected output is

```
{"A": [
         { 'key1 a' : 'value1',
           'key2 a' : 'A B'
           'key3 a' : 'xyz'
         },

         { 'key1 a' : 'value3',  
           'key2 a' : 'value4'
           'key3 a' : 'xyz' 
         }
       ],
 "B": [
         { 'key1 b' : 'value1',
           'key2 b' : 'A C'
           'key3 b' : 'xyz'
         },


         { 'key1 b' : 'value3',  
           'key2 b' : 'value4'
           'key3 b' : 'xyz' 
         }
       ]
}
```

What I have done so far is

```
for k,v in final_dict.iteritems():
     i=0
     j=len(v)
     while i < j:
          if((not(v[i]["key1 a"])) and (not(v[i]["key3 a"]))):
                 v[i-1]["key2 a"] = v[i-1]["key2 a"] + v[i]["key2 a"] 
                 v.pop(i)
                 del v[i]
                 j=j-1
          else:
                 i=i+1
```

Comment: You forgot to ask a question.

Comment: I would like to concatenate the value of a dictionary whose all other fields are empty other than key2 if this holds true then the value of key2 should be concatenated with the previous dictionaries key2 and should delete itself. How could i achieve that. What i tried gives me an error saying "list index out of range"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this is what you are looking for:

```
dict2 = {}
listElem = []
for key,value in dict1.iteritems():
    for listelem_dict in value:
        for sub_k, sub_v in listelem_dict.iteritems():
            if sub_k.startswith(('key1','key3')) and sub_v == '':
                continue
            else:
                listElem.append(listelem_dict)
                break
        break
    dict2[key] = listElem
print dict2
```

with the dict1 is the data structure mentioned below: In your given data structure a few comma's were missing. Assuming missing comma is a typo error.

```
dict1 = {"A": [
                     { 'key1 a' : 'value1',
                       'key2 a' : 'A',
                       'key3 a' : 'xyz'
                     },

                     { 'key1 a' : '',
                       'key2 a' : 'B',
                       'key3 a' : '' 
                     },

                     { 'key1 a' : 'value3',  
                       'key2 a' : 'value4',
                       'key3 a' : 'xyz' 
                     }
              ],
         "B": [
                     { 'key1 b' : 'value1',
                       'key2 b' : 'A',
                       'key3 b' : 'xyz'
                     },

                     { 'key1 b' : '',
                       'key2 b' : 'C',
                       'key3 b' : '' 
                     },

                     { 'key1 b' : 'value3',  
                       'key2 b' : 'value4',
                       'key3 b' : 'xyz' 
                     }
              ]
        }
```